# Adding Multiple NG-QUILL Editors on click of a Add button

Tags: angular

In my Angular 6 application, I want to Add Multiple NG-QUILL Editors on click of a button.

```
 <mat-accordion *ngFor="let sectiondata of ViewDalContent?.sections; index as i">
    <mat-expansion-panel class="viewdal" id="{{sectiondata?.id}" multi="false">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header class="mat-primary">`enter code here`
        <mat-panel-title>{{sectiondata?.title}}</mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div *ngIf="data?.description!== null" class="clause-action-btn-holder">
        <span><button class="ct-dark-blue btn" (click)="showEditClauseEditor($event,i)">Add</button></span>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="isEditEditClauseEditor">
        <quill-editor placeholder="Enter Text"
                      [modules]="quillConfig"
                      (onSelectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
                      (onContentChanged)="onContentChanged($event)"></quill-editor>
      </div>
      <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
        <!--<button class="search-clause-btn btn ct-dark-blue" (click)="showClauseSearchPanel(sectiondata.id)">Search Clause</button>-->
        <div *ngFor="let data of ViewDalContent?.items ">
          <div *ngIf='data?.sectionView?.id === sectiondata?.id'>
            <div id="clause" *ngIf='data?.subType.toLowerCase()==="clause"' [ngClass]="{'remove-clause': (data.partitionKey === '')}">
              {{data.title}}
              <div *ngIf="data?.description!==null">
                <div [innerHTML]="data?.description"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <br />
    </mat-expansion-panel>
    <br/>
  </mat-accordion>
```

In the above code am Looping through the sections first and then in Each section there will be a Add button . Once we click that Add button the Quill Editor needs to come up.Am facing 2 challenges here.

1. If I click Add button Editor is being Added in all the sections, where as it needs to be added ONLY in that section where I have clicked the add button.
2. I need to add Multiple editors in the Same section. i.e I should be able to click Add multiple times in the same section.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Question is not clear.  Can you create a stackblitz. `<quill-editor>` is outside of *ngFor. There can only one one or zero instance of `quill-editor`.

Comment: @dasfdsa , Unfortunately I was not ale to create a stackcblitz. I have edited my code above there you can see am Looping this Quill in a a ngfor loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that show/hide of all editor is dependent on a single variable `isEditEditClauseEditor`. If you make it true, all editor show, and vice versa.

You can create an array for keep track for each editor.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6vp6j) is stackblitz to give you some idea.

Comment: Any way to do this uisng the index ?. Because we never know how many clauses a section may contain. Thanks for taking the time.